# In Notion, why are some pages displaying page descriptions and some other not, and how to change it?

Tags: notion, notion-js

In Notion, I have some pages where when I hover with the mouse over the page Title or the cover image, I get a little grey button between the cover and the title saying "Afficher la Description" (Display the description).

If I click on it I get a full text editable explanation for the page. This is very handy and I would like to generalize it.

However, I dont get how to do it.

First, it seems to be restricted to pages that are databases views.

Second it does not apply to every database I use.

I looked everywhere in Notion Help but did not find anything. Some external site suggest that it might be related to javascript code, but this does not tell me how to do it.  Any idea ?

Edit: I am on Notion.app on a Mac.